# Are there references of Devi Bhagavata Purana in other puranas?

Tags: devi-bhagavata-purana

Devi Bhagavatam itself claimed as bhagavata purana. Is it mentioned in other Puranas?

Comment: [Most of Puranas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35799/12304) simply mention Bhagavata...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226604.html) of Shiva Purana first gives the name of all 18 Puranas as:

> अष्टादश पुराणानि प्रणिनाय स्वलीलया ।। ११९ ।।
> ब्राह्मं पाद्मं वैष्णवञ्च शैवं भागवतं तथा ।।
> भविष्यं नारदीयं च मार्कंडेयमतः परम् ।। 5.44.१२०।।
> आग्नेयं ब्रह्मवैवर्त लिंगं वाराहमेव च ।।
> वामनाख्यं ततः कौर्मं मात्स्यं गारुडमेव च ।।१२१।।
> स्कान्दं तथैव ब्रह्माण्डाख्यं पुराणं च कीर्तितम् ।।
> यशस्यं पुण्यदं नॄणां श्रोतॄणां शांकरं यश ।।१२२।। (Shiva Purana 5.44) 
> The eighteen Purāṇas Brāhma, Pādma. Vaiṣṇava, Śaiva, Bhāgavata, Bhaviṣya, Nāradīya, Mārkaṇḍeya, Āgneya, Brahmavaivarta, Laiṅga, Vārāha, Vāmana Kaurma, Mātsya, Gāruḍa, Skānda and Brahmāṇḍa are conducive to fame and merit to those who listen to the glory of Śiva.

Then, Suta asks Vyasa to describe in short what all these 18 Puranas contain. Vyasa replies that this same question was asked by the Sage Tandi to Nandi and what Nandi says is:

> यत्र वक्ता स्वयन्तण्डे ब्रह्मा साक्षाच्चतुर्मुखः।।
> तस्माद्ब्रह्मं समाख्यातं पुराणं प्रथमं मुने।१२५।
> पद्मकल्पस्य माहात्म्यन्तत्र यस्यामुदाहृतम् ।।
> तस्मात्पाद्मं समाख्यातं पुराणं च द्वितीयकम् ।।१२६।।
> पराशरकृतं यत्तु पुराणं विष्णुबोधकम् ।।
> तदेव व्यासकथितं पुत्रपित्रोरभेदतः ।। १२७ ।।
> यत्र पूर्वोत्तरे खण्डे शिवस्य चरितं बहु ।।
> शैवमेतत्पुराणं हि पुराणज्ञा वदन्ति च ।। १२८ ।।
> **भगवत्याश्च दुर्गायाश्चरितं यत्र विद्यते ।।**
> **तत्तु भागवतं प्रोक्तं ननु देवीपुराणकम् ।।** १२९।।
> नारदोक्तं पुराणन्तु नारदीयं प्रचक्षते ।।
> यत्र वक्ताऽभवत्तण्डे मार्कण्डेयो महामुनिः ।। 5.44.१३० ।।
> मार्कण्डेयपुराणं हि तदाख्यातं च सप्तमम् ।।
> अग्नियोगात्तदाग्नेयं भविष्योक्तेर्भविष्यकम् ।। १३१ ।। (Shiva Purana 5.44) 
> O Taṇḍi, Brahma the four-faced deity is the main speaker. Hence, O sage, the first Purāṇa is called Brāhma. The second Purāṇa is called Padma. It is so called because it mentions the greatness of the Padmakalpa. Another Purāṇa composed by Parāśara and enlightening the details of Viṣṇu is called Vaiṣṇava Purāṇa. It is said to be composed by Vyāsa since there is no difference between father and son. Those who know the Purāṇas speak that purāṇa as Śiva Purāṇa wherein there are many stories of Śiva in its earlier and later forms. **Where the stories of the goddess Durgā are mentioned, it is said to be Bhāgavata Purāṇa as well as Devīpurāṇa.** The Purāṇa narrated by Nārada is called Nāradīya. The seventh Purāṇa is called, O Taṇḍi, Mārkaṇḍeya because the great sage Mārkaṇḍeya is the speaker therein. Since it is related to the fire-god, the Purāṇa is called Āgneya. Since it recounts future events the Purāṇa is called the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa.

Thus, as per Shiva Purana the Purana which contains stories of Durga Devi is the Bhagvata Purana and is also called Devi Purana.

Comment: Damn, i was looking for this from a long time, thanks

Answer (score 1):

> एवमन्यानि सर्वाणि अक्षराण्याह भारती । लिप्यानयैव लिखितं पुराणं तु
> प्रशस्यस्ते ५०। ब्राह्मं पाद्मं वैष्णवं च मार्तंडं नारदेरितम् ।
> मार्कंडेयमथाग्नेयं कौर्मं वामनमेव च ५१। गारुडं लैंगमाख्यातं स्कांदं
> मात्स्यं नृसिंहकम् । तथैव गदितं राम पुराणं कापिलं तथा ५२। वाराहं
> ब्रह्मवैवर्तं शकुनेषु प्रशस्यते । शैवं भागवतं **दौर्गं**
> भविष्योत्तरमेव च ५३। भविष्यं चोपसंज्ञानि त्वन्यानि च विवर्जयेत् ।
>
> 50b-54a. That Purāṇa which is written in this script alone, is
> praiseworthy. (The Purāṇas are:) Brahma, Padma, Vaiṣṇava, Mārtaṇḍa,
> (the one) narrated by Nārada, Mārkaṇḍeya, and Āgneya, Kaurma and
> Vāmana, Gāruḍa; Laiṅga (is also) said (to be one of them); Skānda,
> Mātsya, Nṛsiṃha; O Rāma, Kapila is also said to be (a Purāṇa); so also
> Varāha; Brahmavaivarta is recommended for omens; (and there are) Śiva,
> Bhāgavata, **Daurga (i.e. of Durgā)**, Bhaviṣyottara also known by the
> subtitle Bhaviṣya. One should avoid others.

[~  Padma purana, Pātāla-Khaṇḍa, Chapter 104](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365416.html)

Padma purana mentions Devi Bhagavata by the name Daurga (Purana related to Durga)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, offcourse it is.

> “That Purana which begins with the description of the sacred Gayatri worship, and elaborates various dharma-s, and which contains the narration of the slaying of vrittrasura, is called ‘Bhagavatam’. **That Purana which narrates the stories of the great men of ‘Sarasvata kalpa’, is known as ‘Bhagavatam’.** One who writes Bhagavatam and gives away in charity along with a golden Lion, on the full-moon day, in the month of ‘Bhadrapada’, attains final emancipation. This Purana contains eighteen thousand verses”. (Matsya Purana 53:20-22).

It's the 5th Purana in the list.

> “Vyâsa said :– O King! Maharsi Nârada thus kindling knowledge in me, went away; I also thought over his words. **On the banks of the river Sarasvatî, I composed this (Devî) Bhâgavatam to pass away my time during the excellent period of Sârasvata Kalpa.”** (Devi Bhagavatam 6:31:26-27).

> “O Saumya! (one of gentle appearance) you have recited those Purânas endowed with five characteristics and full of many narratives; of these,**the fifth Purâna,** equivalent to the Vedas and with all the good qualities, the Bhâgavata yields Dharma and Kâma (religion and desires), gives liberation to those who desire for emancipation and is very wonderful; you mentioned this before but ordinarily; you did not dwell on this specially. Now these Brâhmanas are eager to hear gladly this divine auspicious Bhâgavata, the best of the Purânas; so kindly describe this in detail”. (Devi Bhagawatam 1:1:15b-18).

> “**So the Bhagawatam the Purana of Devi is superior than the supreme and greatest among the scriptures** which confer dharma, artha, kama and moksha, is the opinion (of learned ones)”. (Skanda Purana : Devi Bhagawata Mahatmayam : Ch1: verse 37).

> **“The Purana in which the story of the goddess Durga has been enshrined, it is called the ‘Bhagavatam’ or the ‘Devi Purana'”** (Shiva Purana:5:44:129).

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..